# Same dependency as "ejb" and "jar" - what happens?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Dependencies in Maven have a `type` element which defaults to `jar`, but can be set to `ejb`, `war`, `ear`, etc. The type `ejb` is a special case because it does not lead to a different file ending: The `ejb` has still the ending `.jar`.

I have an ear project where the same dependency is referenced once with type `ejb` and once with type `jar` (in the transitive dependency tree). Both entries ask for the very same file, with different Maven "coordinates".

From the perspective of the `dependencyConvergence` rule of the enforcer plugin, both dependencies seem to be *different* - the version of the  `<type>jar` dependency is seemingly not managed by dependencyManagement. Nevertheless, only one of the dependencies makes it into the `ear` - namely the `<type>ejb` one.

When does Maven "drop" the second dependency and what can I do to influence this?

Please note: I know that you shouldn't have `ejb`s as `jar`s on your dependency list, but if I kill the responsible developers, I might go to prison.

Comment: So you're using the standard structure for the lib directory of the EAR? What if you use [`fileNameMapping`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#fileNameMapping) to `full`?

Comment: I use the standard structure: ejbs go to the main directory, other jars to the lib dir. If I just declare a type-jar dependency on an ejb (and not the type-ejb one), it goes to the lib dir. Up to know, I use "no-version" fileNameMapping because I need Class-Path entries in the manifest.mf so that ejbs can see each other (and that is difficult if you have to know the version number in advance).

Comment: Actually, I would be happy if the "dependencyConvergence" works and the type-jar dependencies on ejbs are either mixed in or ignored. I don't want to add dependencyManagement entries twice, once for type-ejb and once for type-jar.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only solution to that. But You can try to set the dependency as provided. If it is on your classpath it robably could reach it, but I had no chanse to try it...

Comment: Are you saying that if you declare both `ejb` and `jar` dependencies in the EAR file pom.xml then one of them is removed? I would expect to get a copy of the jar both in the root of the EAR and in the `lib` directory. This would create significant issues at runtime though - which is then a different problem. Also, do you have more than one EJB jar?

Comment: The ejb does _not_ go to the lib dir (for whatever reason). Having a "double jar" is also not desirable at runtime, as you said. We have dozens of ejb jars (I cannot change that).

Answer (score 1):

I created two sample projects in Eclipse: one EAR, one EJB.

If the order in the EAR's POM is:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <type>jar</type>

<dependency>
  ...
  <type>ejb</type>
```

the `ejb.jar` is put to `.ear`'s `/lib` only.

If the order in the EAR's POM is:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <type>ejb</type>

<dependency>
  ...
  <type>jar</type>
```

the `ejb.jar` is put to  `.ear`'s root and `/lib`.

Apparently one of the rare cases where order of declaration in the POM matters.

BTW, just to make it clear: Your "*the same dependency is referenced* [...] *with different Maven 'coordinates'*" is contradicting. [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) are `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` (GAV), not `packaging` and/or `classifier`, because the latter two don't specify the "Where?" but the "What?". It's probably that why you quoted "coordinates".